# Splitting the count value from my group by, sqlalchemy flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So here is my problem i am trying to display a table which basically shows the amount of sales of a specific model of a car. Like this one,
[image: Table]

Unfortunately i dont know how to separate the amount counted for from the model. Is there any callback or split function that can help me with that?

Here is the code for the html template

```
<div class="table-responsive-lg mt-4 px-4 pt-4 p-0" style="font-size: 14px;">
<table class="table table-dark text-center mx-auto my-0 " style="width: 50%; opacity: .9; padding-top: 50px;">
        <div class="bg-dark mx-auto px-1 mb-0 text-center" style="width: 769px; opacity: .9;">
        <p class="m-0">Tabela dos modelos mais vendidos</p>
        </div>
<thead>
    <tr>
        {% for cabeca2 in TituloTop20Modelo %}
            <th scope= 'col'> {{ cabeca2 }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    {% for numero in ContadorGrupo %}
    <td>
        {{numero.ModeloDB}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{numero}}
    </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}        
</tbody>
</table>
```

And here it is the specific query i used to get the variables.

```
return render_template("TerceiraJanela.html",TituloTop20Modelo= TituloTop20Modelo, ContadorGrupo= Dado.query.with_entities(Dado.ModeloDB, func.count(Dado.ModeloDB)).group_by(Dado.ModeloDB).all())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to label my columns to make this easier:

You've got:

`Dado.query.with_entities(Dado.ModeloDB, func.count(Dado.ModeloDB)).group_by(Dado.ModeloDB).all())`

Change that to (using the `label`):

`Dado.query.with_entities(Dado.ModeloDB, func.count(Dado.ModeloDB).label('sold')).group_by(Dado.ModeloDB).all())`

So now in your template can use:

`numero.ModeloDB` and `numero.sold` to refer to the values.